# acer Aspire R7 with touchscreen

Tags: touchscreen

I just got an acer Aspire R7 and it has a touchscreen.
Can I install ubuntu on it and with the touchscreen work? 
I'm planing on install it soon.

Comment: Please, when asking a question, can you supply as much information as possible. This will help people to help you. Can you add Make and model of your computer, RAM and Processor information and any other relevant information to your question, please.

Answer (score 1):

Just tested on Ubuntu 13.10 - touchscreen works great!